# UIButton won't change bounds programmatically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton, bounds

I am making an iPhone game where I have the user selecting what color they want their car to be in the game. To show which cars can be selected I have UIButtons with background images that are the various cars. To show which car is currently selected I have a button behind the current car color that has a background color of yellow. What I want to happen is that when you click on a car button the yellow button moves behind the button that was clicked. My code looks like:

```
    -(void)setPlayerCar:(UIButton *)newCar{
    //this code is being called when any of the buttons is clicked
    NSArray *carFiles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"redCar.png",@"blueCar.png",@"greenCar.png",@"purpleCar.png",@"turquioseCar.png",@"yellowCar.png", nil];
    NSString *file = [carFiles objectAtIndex:newCar.tag];
    currentCarImage = file;
    CGRect frame;
    if(currentCarImage == @"redCar.png"){
        frame = CGRectMake(48, 78, 30, 30);
    }
    if(currentCarImage == @"blueCar.png"){
        frame = CGRectMake(83, 78, 30, 30);
    }
    if(currentCarImage == @"greenCar.png"){
        frame = CGRectMake(118, 78, 30, 30);
    }
    if(currentCarImage == @"purpleCar.png"){
        frame = CGRectMake(153, 78, 30, 30);
    }
    if(currentCarImage == @"turquioseCar.png"){
        frame = CGRectMake(188, 78, 30, 30);
    }
    if(currentCarImage == @"yellowCar.png"){
        frame = CGRectMake(223, 78, 30, 30);
    }
    for(UIButton *button in self.pauseScroll.subviews){
        if(button.backgroundColor == [UIColor yellowColor]){
           button.bounds = frame;
        }
        if(button.tag == newCar.tag){
           [self.pauseScroll bringSubviewToFront:button];
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know this should move the yellow colored button over to the button that was selected. The problem is this doesn't happen, when I debug I find that the correct button is being recognized and that frame is being given the right value and that the line: button.bounds = frame; is being executed but when I look at what is being displayed nothing has changed.

Comment: `currentCarImage == @"redCar.png"` this is not how you compare strings you need `[currentCarImage isEqualToString:@"redCar.png"]`

Comment: I would also consider changing the `if` statements to `else if` statements so that you don't perform every test every time. Also the `carFiles` array would be better placed somewhere else most likely in an ivar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be changing the `frame` of the button and not the `bounds`. The `bounds` of a view describe a view's location and size in its own coordinate space. The `frame` is the size and location in the superview's coordinate space.

```
if (button.backgroundColor == [UIColor yellowColor]) {
    button.frame = frame;
}
```